# Function does not exist on type '() => any'. ts(2339) IONIC4, ANGULAR, FIREBASEAUTH

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I am trying to link Firebase Authentication to the Firestore Lists in order to add an additional field for users of my app but my function updateUserData function on my login page gives me this error

> 'Property 'updateUserData' does not exist on type '() => any'.ts(2339)'

//Login function from login.page.ts

```
async OpenPortal() {
const { email, password } = this;
   try {
      const res = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
       email + '@smartpark.com',
       password
       );
     return this.OpenPortal.updateUserData(res.user);
     this.router.navigate(['admin-portal']);
   } catch (err) {
     console.dir(err);
     if (err.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
     console.log('User not Found');
    }
  }
}
```

//user.model.ts

```
export interface User {
uid: string;
email: string;
photoURL?: string;
displayName?: string;
accountType?: string;

 }
```

//auth.service.ts

```
export class AuthService {


user$: Observable<User>;

constructor(
  private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private afs: AngularFirestore,
  private router: Router
) { 
  this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      if (user) { 
         return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();      
          }
      })
    );

  }
```

I expect that the firebase authentication list will be linked to my users list in the firestore list to show the users account type, whether it is admin, staff or student.

Comment: `this.OpenPortal.updateUserData`... ? `OpenPortal` is the class function you defined here..  `updateUserData` doesnt exist inside the function